# Find instance that has specified attribute

Tags: sql, sqlite

| name | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | data1 |
| item2 | data1 |
| item3 | data2 |
| item1 | data2 |
| item2 | data3 |
| item4 | data3 |
| item3 | data2 |
| item5 | data3 |

I am trying to find names that *only* have attribute `data3`. Expected output :

| name |
| --- |
| item4 |
| item5 |

My solution was to `SELECT name FROM TABLE` then `EXCEPT SELECT name WHERE attribute!="data3"` but this included more items than expected output. I am trying to solve the problem with set operations such as EXCEPT, UNION, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NOT IN` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    name
FROM
    table
WHERE
    attribute = 'data3'
    AND
    name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM table WHERE attribute != 'data3')
;
```

Or using `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE attribute  = 'data3'
EXCEPT
SELECT name FROM table WHERE attribute != 'data3'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   name
from     t
group by name
having   max(attribute) = 'data3'
and      max(attribute) = min(attribute)
```

| name |
| --- |
| item4 |
| item5 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KCZtDnX6)